# Pythonic way to check if number falls in a certain range

Tags: python, conditional-statements

The following code assigns a certain value to the `a` variable depending on the range that the `v` variable falls in.

```
if v>0 and v<1000:
    c='green'
elif v>=1000 and v<2000:
    c='yellow'
else:
    c='red'
```

That works well, but I was wondering if there is a more Pythonic way to write the following conditional block.

Comment: I answered but im pretty sure there is a canonical dupe around here somewhere

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`0 < v < 1000`

thats all ...

## edit

this would work for your specific use case

```
var_color = ['green', 'yellow', 'red'][(v >= 1000) + (v >= 2000)]
```

Comment: Looks good. There is no way to escape the conditional statements I assume. Correct?

Comment: escape the conditional statements? oh I see umm theres always a way ...

Comment: `['green', 'yellow', 'red'][(v >= 1000) + (v >= 2000)]`

Comment: @MuhammadYounus If you think this code is Pythonic, I encourage you to review your understanding.